# Something do not work with background on website

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying do someting like that (background image cover full page)
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_fullpage_demo.htm
I have no idea why my code do not work. Maybe it is something with html, thats why I deleted most of code to check it, what did not work. That why I thought that was a problem with css. But i do not know. Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "pl">
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />

<meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<!--<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" /> -->

<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

.clear{
clear:both;
}
#head{
/*https://pixabay.com/pl/users/Tama66-1032521/*/
background-image:url("railway.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height:100%;
}

#space1{
width:20%;
float:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "container">
<header>
<div id = "head">
<div id = "menu">

<div id = "space1">
</div>

<div id = "menulist">
<ol id = list>
<li><a href = "#"></a></li>
<li><a href = "#"></a></li>
<li><a href = "#"></a></li>
<li><a href = "#"></a></li>
</ol>
</div>

<div class = "clear">
</div>

</div>
</div>
</header>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting `height:100%` on the `body`, you also need to add this

```
html{height:100%}
```

When you set `height:100%` on any element, it means you are asking the element to take up as much height as the *parent element's height*. The parent element needs to have some height *explicitly* specified. Only then will it work(with the exception of a `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` on the element). Here, you didn't specify `height` on the `body`'s parent, `html`. You might ask that whose height should `html` base it's own height on. That, I don't have an answer to. Perhaps someone looking at this question will have an answer.

Comment: Ok. I'm rewriting it followed by your instructions, from the begining it working. So i don't know why something didn't work in previous site.

Comment: @Daniel1490 You didn't add `html{height:100%}`

Answer (score 1):

```
#head{
/*https://pixabay.com/pl/users/Tama66-1032521/*/
background-image:url("railway.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height:100vh;
```

}

try to change 100% to 100vh...

Comment: If you use 100% as height, you have to set the body to min-height 100%, max-height 100%, and height to 100%. But if you watch the page on a phone or something, idk for sure if it is working.. 100 VH stands for 100 Viewport Height, on every device, your image will be 100% of the device height automatic